# Is it possible for 2 columns in one table to be joined to the same second table?

Tags: sql, join

Apologies if the answer is something simple but I'm a bit new to this.

Essentially I have two tables.

1) This table details a persons biographic details with the following columns.

Forename | Surname | DOB - Day | DOB - Month | Dob Year

2) This table is a reference table called "codebook" its used as a lookup 
and has the following columns

Key | Value

In the first table, both the "DOB - Day" and "DOB - Month" reference the "codebook table" (this is because these two columns are actually combo boxes within an applications so the values that are stored here reference the codebook table)

My problem is when I'm trying to query the database - essentially I want the results that are displayed to the user to show the actual values for the "DOB - Day" and "DOB - Month" column's rather than the ID that's actually stored in the first table.

I'll add some simple data to both tables for context.

Table 1

```
Forename    Surname   DOB - Day     DOB - Month     DOB - Year
Sam         Smith     DOB_DAY_1     DOB_MONTH_6     1987
Tom         Nickles   DOB_DAY_13    DOB_MONTH_4     1974
Abigail     Peters    DOB_DAY_17    DOB_MONTH_10    2000
Marcus      Tompson   DOB_DAY_5     DOB_MONTH_11    2002
Rick        Ford                                    2000
```

Table 2

```
Key          Value
DOB_DAY_1    1
DOB_DAY_2    2
DOB_DAY_3    3
DOB_MONTH_1  January
DOB_MONTH_2  February
DOB_MONTH_3  March
```

I've tried to use a equi-join on the tables so that "DOB - Day" = "Key" and "DOB - Month" = "key" however I have a problem where if a DOB isn't known for a person they aren't shown in the results because equi-joins discount null values.

What I need in a outer join but Microsoft query editor says I can only have one outer-join so I can only reference one of the columns …

I'm clearly not understanding something critical because it must be possible for two columns in the same table to reference the same second table. Would sub queries fix this problem?

Any help would be massively appreciated, and if you could dumb it down for me that'd be great as well haha.

Comment: Pl share what you have tried? From what you have mentioned in the question text, i assume you are using MS Sql Server.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need instead of an equi-join is a left join. A left join B. Means it will show everything from table A even though a lookup value was not found in table B.

```
SELECT T.Forename,T.Surname,Day.Value as DOBDay,Month.Values as DOBMonth,T.[DOB - Year]
FROM Test as T
LEFT JOIN CodeBook as Day ON Day.Key=T.[DOB - Day]
LEFT JOIN CodeBook as Month ON Month.Key=T.[DOB - Month]
```